# Validate password fields while current password field has value in magento

Tags: validation, magento, prototypejs

I'm having change password form in magento Account Information page.Here I want to validate password fields(password,confirm password,current password) while current password has value.Otherwise it should not validate.

In magento 1.5.1.0 [really easy field validation](http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation) is used to validate the forms.

I know **addClassName** add the validate like below

```
    $('current_password').addClassName('required-entry');
    $('password').addClassName('required-entry');
    $('confirmation').addClassName('required-entry');
```

**removeClassName** this one removes validation

```
$('current_password').removeClassName('required-entry');
$('password').removeClassName('required-entry');
$('confirmation').removeClassName('required-entry');
```

But how can i apply only while current_password has value.I'm not familiar with prototype.js functions .Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that template file, you can put a check in PHP around the javascript to add or remove validation. For example,

```
<?php if ($customer->getCurrentPassword()): ?>
    $('something').doStuff(); //however you want the logic to work
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't think php going to help me. validation should occur while onchange or onblur. always Current Password field will be empty.if we decide we can modify.

Comment: :observer is not working for the onblur   $(element).observe('onblur', function(event){.how can i make it

Comment: try `$(element).observe('blur', function (event) {});`